# loading observableArray

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout in Typescript, I want to load data returned from db into an observableArray.

I tried the below code, but I got an exception:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'map'

in constructor:

```
this.boxes = ko.observableArray<Box>(data[0].box || []).map(e => new Box(
                e.index,
                e.title,
                e.value,
                e.category
            ));


this.boxes = ko.observableArray<Box>([]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is a method on a normal JavaScript array, not an `ObservableArray`, so you need to perform the mapping on the array from the response data before passing it to `ko.observableArray<Box>()`:

```
this.boxes = ko.observableArray<Box>((data[0].box || []).map(e => new Box(
            e.index,
            e.title,
            e.value,
            e.category
        )));
```